# Discord.js How i check id of members all guilds?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

## Discord.js Version 11.4.2

Answer in below

```js
  if(message.content === '!listid'){
    console.log("See id members all guild")
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

## Discord.js Version 11.4.2

1.We need to check id of guild first

2.Get id of guild

3.Console.log members id of guild

```js
  if(message.content === '!listid'){
    client.guilds.forEach(member => {
      console.log(`${member.id}`)

      var idserver = (`${member.id}`) // id each guild
      var memserver = client.guilds.get(idserver); // check guild with id

      memserver.members.forEach(member => {
        console.log(member.user.id); // console.log see id user in that guild
      }); // get userid all guild
    });
  };
```